# Formik / Yup Validation for Register Form on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, formik, yup

I am learning react and I have decided to create a React Front End that connects to Express.js on back-end. At the moment, I am trying to add validation on my register/login forms. I dont really understand how the validation system is implemented. I've noticed that tutorials use functional components for Formik/Yup however, I am using a class based component.

My register page doesn't display anything when i try to render it. Of course, I must have implemented this incorrectly, I cant figure out what to do. Thank you for help.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { register } from "./UserFunctions";
import { Formik, Field } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

// const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
//   first_name: yup.string
// })

class Register extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      first_name: "",
      last_name: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      errors: {},
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //new user object
    const newUser = {
      first_name: this.state.first_name,
      last_name: this.state.last_name,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
    };

    //if register function succesful, redirect to login page
    register(newUser).then((res) => {
      this.props.history.push(`/login`);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6 mt-5 mx-auto">
            <Formik
              initialValues={{
                first_name: "",
                last_name: "",
                email: "",
                password: "",
              }}
              validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
                first_name: Yup.string()
                  .required("First Name is Required.")
                  .min(1, "First Name is Too Short."),
                last_name: Yup.string()
                  .required("Last Name is Required.")
                  .min(1, "Last Name is Too Short."),
                email: Yup.string().email().required("Email is Required."),
                password: Yup.string()
                  .required("No password provided.")
                  .min(8, "Password is too short - should be 8 chars minimum.")
                  .matches(/(?=.*[0-9])/, "Password must contain a number."),
              })}
            >
              {(props) => {
                const {
                  touched,
                  errors,
                  isSubmitting,
                  handleChange,
                  handleBlur,
                  handleSubmit,
                } = props;
                <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                  <h1 className="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Register</h1>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="name">First name</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      name="first_name"
                      placeholder="Enter your first name"
                      value={this.state.first_name}
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                    />
                    {errors.first_name && touched.first_name && (
                      <div className="input-feedback">{errors.first_name}</div>
                    )}
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="name">Last name</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      name="last_name"
                      placeholder="Enter your last name"
                      value={this.state.last_name}
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                    />
                    {errors.last_name && touched.last_name && (
                      <div className="input-feedback">{errors.last_name}</div>
                    )}
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="email">Email address</label>
                    <input
                      type="email"
                      className="form-control"
                      name="email"
                      placeholder="Enter email"
                      value={this.state.email}
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                    />
                    {errors.email && touched.email && (
                      <div className="input-feedback">{errors.email}</div>
                    )}
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                    <input
                      type="password"
                      className="form-control"
                      name="password"
                      placeholder="Password"
                      value={this.state.password}
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                    />
                    {errors.password && touched.password && (
                      <div className="input-feedback">{errors.password}</div>
                    )}
                  </div>
                  <button
                    type="submit"
                    className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
                  >
                    Register!
                  </button>
                </form>;
              }}
            </Formik>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Register;
```

Answer (score 0):

Formik validates the form when trying to submit, if there are any errors it doesn't allow the form to be submitted, it is upto you to display the error messages to the user when he tries to submit with errors see [this page](https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation) for reference

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you need not use state while using Form Libraries. The main purpose of using Form libraries is to encapsulate the state and reduce the boilerplate.
2. **Formik**, itself, is a container for your form state.
3. Please Note :- you should pass the values of the **formik** form data into the input fields by using `values` ( which contains your form data) and `handleChange` provided by formik
4. **Formik** takes `onSubmit` as a prop where you can get your form state after validation and then, here you can register for your new user.

Also, you can check the [codesandbox link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-ramanujan-dwc70?file=/src/App.js:0-4713).

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
// import { register } from "./UserFunctions";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  first_name: Yup.string()
    .required("First Name is Required.")
    .min(1, "First Name is Too Short."),
  last_name: Yup.string()
    .required("Last Name is Required.")
    .min(1, "Last Name is Too Short."),
  email: Yup.string().email().required("Email is Required."),
  password: Yup.string()
    .required("No password provided.")
    .min(8, "Password is too short - should be 8 chars minimum.")
    .matches(/(?=.*[0-9])/, "Password must contain a number.")
});

class Register extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6 mt-5 mx-auto">
            <Formik
              initialValues={{
                first_name: "",
                last_name: "",
                email: "",
                password: ""
              }}
              validationSchema={schema}
              // tell the formik to validate onBlur
              validateOnBlur
              onSubmit={(values) => {
                // here you have the access to the form data
                // values.first_name, values_last_name, values_email, values_password 
                //if register function succesful, redirect to login page
                // register(values).then((res) => {
                //   this.props.history.push(`/login`);
                // })
              }}
            >
              {(props) => {
                const {
                  touched,
                  errors,
                  handleSubmit,
                  values,
                  handleChange,
                  handleBlur,
                } = props;

                return (
                  <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <h1 className="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Register</h1>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="name">First name</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        name="first_name"
                        placeholder="Enter your first name"

                        value={values.first_name}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                      />
                      {errors.first_name && touched.first_name && (
                        <div className="input-feedback">
                          {errors.first_name}
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="name">Last name</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        name="last_name"
                        placeholder="Enter your last name"
                        value={values.last_name}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                      />
                      {errors.last_name && touched.last_name && (
                        <div className="input-feedback">{errors.last_name}</div>
                      )}
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="email">Email address</label>
                      <input
                        type="email"
                        className="form-control"
                        name="email"
                        placeholder="Enter email"
                        value={values.email}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                      />
                      {errors.email && touched.email && (
                        <div className="input-feedback">{errors.email}</div>
                      )}
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                      <input
                        type="password"
                        className="form-control"
                        name="password"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        value={values.password}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                      />
                      {errors.password && touched.password && (
                        <div className="input-feedback">{errors.password}</div>
                      )}
                    </div>
                    <button
                      type="submit"
                      className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
                    >
                      Register!
                    </button>
                  </form>
                );
              }}
            </Formik>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Register;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The only problem I am having with the code you have given is that it won't provide instant feedback when each field is touched. That is a feature I wanted... e.g. user clicks first-name and doesnt enter anything, the app should display error straight away

Comment: at the moment, it only displays the errors when you click Submit, How do i get the instant feedback to work?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/4203r4582w?file=/src/ValidatedLoginForm.js I wanted something like this :)

Comment: @HT you could add `validateOnBlur` on Formik as a prop and use `handleBlur` given by **formik** and pass it to the input field. I have updated the code example and sandbox link.

Answer (score 0):

That is your code with functional component and with fewer code lines, it's working as expected

```
import React from "react";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import { register } from "./UserFunctions";
import * as Yup from "yup";

const Register = ({ history }) => {
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    first_name: Yup.string()
      .required("First Name is Required.")
      .min(1, "First Name is Too Short."),
    last_name: Yup.string()
      .required("Last Name is Required.")
      .min(1, "Last Name is Too Short."),
    email: Yup.string().email().required("Email is Required."),
    password: Yup.string()
      .required("No password provided.")
      .min(8, "Password is too short - should be 8 chars minimum.")
      .matches(/(?=.*[0-9])/, "Password must contain a number."),
  });

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      first_name: "",
      last_name: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },

    validationSchema: validationSchema,

    onSubmit: (values) => {
      const newUser = {
        first_name: values.first_name,
        last_name: values.last_name,
        email: values.email,
        password: values.password,
      };

      //if register function succesful, redirect to login page
      register(newUser).then((res) => {
        history.push(`/login`);
      });
    },
  });

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6 mt-5 mx-auto">
          <form noValidate onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
            <h1 className="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Register</h1>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="name">First name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name="first_name"
                placeholder="Enter your first name"
                value={formik.values.first_name}
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
              />
              {formik.errors.first_name && formik.touched.first_name && (
                <div className="input-feedback">{formik.errors.first_name}</div>
              )}
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="name">Last name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name="last_name"
                placeholder="Enter your last name"
                value={formik.values.last_name}
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
              />
              {formik.errors.last_name && formik.touched.last_name && (
                <div className="input-feedback">{formik.errors.last_name}</div>
              )}
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="email">Email address</label>
              <input
                type="email"
                className="form-control"
                name="email"
                placeholder="Enter email"
                value={formik.values.email}
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
              />
              {formik.errors.email && formik.touched.email && (
                <div className="input-feedback">{formik.errors.email}</div>
              )}
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
              <input
                type="password"
                className="form-control"
                name="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                value={formik.values.password}
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
              />
              {formik.errors.password && formik.touched.password && (
                <div className="input-feedback">{formik.errors.password}</div>
              )}
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
              Register!
            </button>
          </form>
          ;
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

Comment: I wanted instant feedback like this https://codesandbox.io/s/4203r4582w?file=/src/ValidatedLoginForm.js

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from "react";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import axios from "axios";
import "./Add.scss";
import Header from "../../components/Header"
import { toast, Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";
export default function Add() {
  return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Add</title>
      </Helmet>
      <Header/>
      <div className="formik">
        <div className="form">
          <Formik
            initialValues={{
              title: "",
              price: "",
              image: "",
              desc: "",
            }}
            validationSchema={Yup.object({
              title: Yup.string().required("title is required"),
              price: Yup.number().required("price is required"),
              image: Yup.string().required("image is required"),
              desc: Yup.string().required("desc is required"),
            })}
            onSubmit={(values, { resetForm }) => {
              axios.post("http://localhost:8080/robots", values).then((res) => {
                toast.success("Added new Card");
              });
              resetForm();
            }}
          >
            {({ values, handleChange, handleSubmit, dirty }) => (
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label htmlFor="title" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                  title:
                </label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="title"
                  id="title"
                  value={values.title}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="price">Price:</label>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  placeholder="price"
                  id="price"
                  value={values.price}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />

                <label htmlFor="image">image:</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="image"
                  id="image"
                  value={values.image}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />

                <label htmlFor="desc">Description:</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="desc"
                  id="desc"
                  value={values.desc}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <button type="submit" disabled={!dirty}>
                  Add
                </button>
              </form>
            )}
          </Formik>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Toaster />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.